# Render kml files on google maps locally?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kml

I'm using GeoXML js. for v3 google maps to parse kml files locally. I do not wish to use KmlLayer() as it requires the kml to be on a publicly accessible server. http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage

Originally I have kml files as a byte array in the SQL server database.

I retrieve the byte array from the database and do `File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\KmlFiles\\layer" + id + ".kml", byte[])`,This successfully saves the kml file to the path.

Now I need to pass the kml file into GeoXML parser. I have been trying to pass the directory path to the method, like this, I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var myMap = new google.maps.Map(...);

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: myMap});
    myParser.parse(path);
  </script>
```

This doesn't work. It seems this is not the right way to pass the kml file, as it is not a url. I'm stuck on what i can do to make the kml files render. I have the .Net MVC app where the google maps is embedded, at the moment I'm running the app locally on my PC, haven't published it on the web server (with iis 7) yet.

Please give me an idea of how to go about parsing the kml files. How would I get the url of the kml file? I'm stuck on how to proceed/make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- You can override the ActionResult on your controller action to return a KMLResult
- The action can be secured using Authoize attribute (and login)
- Now you can use KML Layer

IMO downloading the file to the client PC for loading on a Javascript, is not a good idea.

Comment: But the KmlLayer(...) needs a url that should point to a kml file stored in a public server without any security so that Google's server can parse it. Don't I need to save the file to a server first?

Comment: How can I save the KML file to the MVC application directory which will be secured w/o storing to client's PC...I would prefer rendering the KML file locally rather than accessible by anyone. How to use GeoXML that way?

Comment: You can login before loading the page, this will make sure your [Authorize] attribute not needing another login but will ensure only the logged in user is able to access it. I haven't used GeoXML btw.